# overflow-x screws background-color of a div

Tags: html, css

When using overflow-x in a parent div, the background-color of this parent-div will be used only that area which is initially visible, for the hidden/scroll-available part it will not.

http://jsfiddle.net/23yEz/5/

I expect the 'row' classed divs to have proper background (green, blue) everywhere.

```
    .row:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: green;    
}

.row:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: blue;    
}

.col
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

.col2
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 400px;
    min-width: 400px;
}

    <div style="overflow-x: auto; background-color: red; margin-top: 50px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">text 1</div>
        <div class="col">text 2</div>
        <div class="col">text 3</div>
        <div class="col">text 4</div>
        <div class="col">text 5</div>
        <div class="col">text 6</div>
        <div class="col">text 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col2">Row2 Cell 1</div>
        <div class="col2">Row2 Cell 2</div>
        <div class="col2">Row2 Cell 3</div>
        <div class="col2">Row2 Cell 4</div>
        <div class="col2">Row2 Cell 5</div>
        <div class="col2">Row2 Cell 6</div>
        <div class="col2">Row2 Cell 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col2">Row3 Cell 1</div>
        <div class="col2">Row3 Cell 2</div>
        <div class="col2">Row3 Cell 3</div>
        <div class="col2">Row3 Cell 4</div>
        <div class="col2">Row3 Cell 5</div>
        <div class="col2">Row3 Cell 6</div>
        <div class="col2">Row3 Cell 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col2">Row4 Cell 1</div>
        <div class="col2">Row4 Cell 2</div>
        <div class="col2">Row4 Cell 3</div>
        <div class="col2">Row4 Cell 4</div>
        <div class="col2">Row4 Cell 5</div>
        <div class="col2">Row4 Cell 6</div>
        <div class="col2">Row4 Cell 7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto` to `.row` to restore the behavior you seek.

```
.row {
    background-color: green;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/23yEz/2/)**

Comment: OK,  wasn't speific enough. Imagine I have 2-3 rows with different content inside them. I want to scroll them with one scrollbar.

Comment: I have no idea how that comment relates to your original question.

Comment: plesae re-read the question and jsfiddle, i made it more specific